# Is not saving an object instance in Java considered bad practice or totally not?

Tags: java

ex.

```
new SportsCar().drive();
```

vs.

```
SportsCar sc = new SportsCar();
sc.drive();
```

assuming that you have no reason at the moment why you would need to use the instance of SportsCar again?

Comment: If you're not going to reuse the instance, there's no point in storing a reference to it in a variable, except for readability.

Comment: @azurefrog, at which point you can argue either way, making it purely a matter of opinion/taste.

Comment: @azurefrog which is a perfectly valid reason, especially considering the compiler will optimize the variable itself away.

Comment: Truthfully, though, at the point where I don't need the instance that I'm calling the method on it probably means that it should be a static method...

Comment: @user9791370 not necessarily. In this case you might not need the instance again, in other cases you might.

Comment: @MadPhysicist True.  Whether it's more readable with or without the extra variable is a matter of opinion.  I was just trying to point out that the difference is only in the source code, and once compiled it's irrelevant.  I should have been more clear.

Comment: @azurefrog there are plenty of things that are "only different in the source code and irrelevant once compiled"... that doesn't make them not bad practice!

Answer (score 1):

In your example, there is no difference between temporarily saving a reference vs. not. The compiler most likely inlines the two-line version to look like the one-line version.

There might be other reasons it is useful though. For example, you might want to handle exceptions from the constructor differently from the `drive()` method:

```
SportsCar sc;
try {
    sc = new SportsCar();
    try {
        sc.drive();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // handle exceptions thrown by drive()
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // handle exceptions thrown during object construction
}
```